# Django FloatField object has no attribute Error

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I was creating a form in which user will input float number.
My Code:

```
class ApartmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    val1= forms.FloatField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.FloatField(),
    )
    val2= forms.FloatField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.FloatField(),
    )
```

But I am getting this error.

```
AttributeError at /post/
'FloatField' object has no attribute 'is_hidden'
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback, together with the relevant view (and model).

Answer (score 0):

A [**`FloatField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#floatfield) is a *form field*, not a *widget*. You thus can not use this as widget.

What you can do is work with an widget, for example a [**`NumberInput`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.NumberInput), or a [**`TextInput`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.NumberInput), for example:

```
class ApartmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # …
    val1 = forms.FloatField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.NumberInput(),
    )
    val2 = forms.FloatField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.TextInput(),
    )
```

In this code sample, two different widgets are used. That way you can see the effect of picking one widget over the other.